# Agglomerative clustering implementation in python

Tags: python, jupyter, cluster-analysis, hierarchical-clustering

I tried Implementing Agglomerative Clustering Implementation using python. It works for some data sets but gets stuck in between some other datasets. Please help in identifying my mistake. Also,  this code is implemented upon ***Single Linkage*** method. If you have some other alternative to implement this that would also be helpful.

```
X = np.array(([[ 1. , 60.7],
       [ 2. , 45.8],
       [ 3. , 64.8],
       [ 4. , 40.8],
       [ 5. , 72.8],
       [ 6. , 54.8],
       [ 7. , 77.7],
       [ 8. , 42.3],
       [ 9. , 39. ],
       [10. , 59.8],
       [11. , 67.5],
       [12. , 78.3],
       [13. , 43.5],
       [14. , 47.2],
       [15. , 55.8],
       [16. , 62.7],
       [17. , 30.7],
       [18. , 48.2],
       [19. , 32.5],
       [20. , 73.5],
       [21. , 39.2],
       [22. , 48.5],
       [23. , 62.8],
       [24. , 42.2],
       [25. , 64. ],
       [26. , 26.3]]))
def calculate_distance(samples):
    Distance_matrix = np.zeros((len(samples),len(samples)))
    for i in range(Distance_matrix.shape[0]):
        for j in range(Distance_matrix.shape[0]):
            if i!=j:
                Distance_matrix[i,j] = float(distance_calculation(samples[i],samples[j]))
            else:
                Distance_matrix[i,j]=10**4
    return Distance_matrix
   
def distance_calculation(sample1,sample2):
    distance=[]
    for i in range(len(sample1)):
        for j in range(len(sample2)):
            try:
                distance.append(np.linalg.norm(np.array(sample1[i])-np.array(sample2[j])))
            except:
                distance.append(sampledistance(sample1[i],sample2[j]))
    return min(distance)
def sampledistance(sam1,sam2):
    #print('INSIDE SAMPLED_DISTANCE')
    if str(type(sam2[0]))!='<class \'list\'>':
        sam2 = [sam2]
    if str(type(sam1[0]))!='<class \'list\'>':
        sam1 = [sam1]
    m = len(sam1)
    n = len(sam2)
    distance = []
    if n>=m:
        for i in range(n):
            for j in range(m):
                if(len(sam2[i])>=len(sam1[j])) and str(type(sam2[i][0])!='<class \'list\'>'):
                    distance.append(cluster_distance(sam2[i],sam1[j]))
                else:
                    distance.append(np.linalg.norm(np.array(sam2[i])-np.array(sam1[j])))
    else:
        for i in range(m):
            for j in range(n):
                if(len(sam1[i])>=len(sam2[j])) and str(type(sam1[i][0])!='<class \'list\'>'):
                    distance.append(cluster_distance(sam1[i],sam2[j]))
                else:
                    distance.append(np.linalg.norm(np.array(sam1[i])-np.array(sam2[j])))
    return min(distance)
def cluster_distance(clu,sample):
    #print('INSIDE CLUSTER_DISTANCE')
    if sample[0]!= '<class \'list\'>':
        sample = [sample]
    distance = []
    for i in range(len(clu)):
        for j in range(len(sample)):
            distance.append(np.linalg.norm(np.array(clu[i])-np.array(sample[j])))
    return min(distance)
```